# How do I compare values of two JsValues in Rust code?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

In JavaScript, I can do it like this:

```js
JSON.stringify([1,2,3]) ===  JSON.stringify([1,2,3]) // true
```

In Rust compiled to Wasm, I tried something like:

```
#[wasm_bindgen_test]
fn test_algo() {
    let js_array_to_sort = Array::of3(&JsValue::from(1), &JsValue::from(3), &JsValue::from(2));
    let js_array_after_sort = Array::of3(&JsValue::from(1), &JsValue::from(2), &JsValue::from(3));
    let array = JsValue::from(&js_array_to_sort);

    assert_eq!(
        JSON::stringify(BubbleSort::sort(SortArray::new(array))).unwrap(),
        JSON::stringify(JsValue::from(&js_array_after_sort)).unwrap(),
    );
}
```

It raised some error with `wasm-pack test --chrome` about no `partialeq` for `JsString` - a result of `JSON::stringify`:

```
 error[E0277]: can't compare `js_sys::JsString` with `js_sys::JsString`
    --> src/algorithms/bubble.rs:36:5
     |
  36 | /     assert_eq!(
  37 | |         JSON::stringify(&BubbleSort::sort(SortArray::new(array))).unwrap(),
  38 | |         JSON::stringify(&JsValue::from(&js_array_after_sort)).unwrap(),
  39 | |     );
     | |______^ no implementation for `js_sys::JsString == js_sys::JsString`
     |
     = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq` is not implemented for `js_sys::JsString`
```

If I try to convert to a string and compare in some other way (like directly with `JsString` method), I always get the same kind of compiling error.

If I try to compare this array directly, I have similar behavior to this in JavaScript:

```js
JsValue([1,2,3]) == JsValue([1,2,3]) // false
```

In `Cargo.toml` I have:

```
[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.39"
js-sys = "0.3.16"
wasm-bindgen-test = "0.2.39"
```

How do I make this kind of comparison?

Edit.

I come up with something like this to pass this test:

```
  assert_eq!(
        String::from(JSON::stringify(&BubbleSort::sort(SortArray::new(array))).unwrap()),
        String::from(JSON::stringify(&JsValue::from(&js_array_after_sort)).unwrap()),
    );
```

Comment: *It raised some error* — Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Provide the **entire** error without attempting to interpret it. Try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: "In JavaScript, I can do it like this: " - No, you can't. This comparison is false, although the JSON is semantically equal: `JSON.stringify({"foo": 1, "bar": 2}) === JSON.stringify({"bar": 2, "foo": 1})`

Answer (score 2):

Try `Object::is(&first, &second)` from js_sys.

You can use `JSON::stringify(...)` and then compare it in similar way you are doing in JavaScript

```
#[wasm_bindgen_test]
fn test_algo() {
    let js_array_to_sort = Array::of3(&JsValue::from(1), &JsValue::from(2), &JsValue::from(3));
    let js_array_after_sort = Array::of3(&JsValue::from(1), &JsValue::from(2), &JsValue::from(3));
    let to_array = JsValue::from(&js_array_to_sort);
    let from_array = JsValue::from(&js_array_after_sort);
    let to_str: JsString = JSON::stringify(&to_array).unwrap();
    let from_str: JsString = JSON::stringify(&from_array).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(to_str == from_str, true);
    assert_eq!(Object::is(&to_str, &from_str), true);
}
```

Please use your own sorting algorithm. I have taken the values as sorted to compare, if not sorted then you can see the assertion error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24181111)

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I have added explanation there, I think you clicked delete before I submitted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are not supposed to compare them. They don't implement `Eq` or `PartialEq`, and you therefore cannot compare slices or arrays of them.

In fact they don't even live inside Rust, and are simply indexes to values outside.

You probably can't sort them either because they don't implement `Ord`.

The idiomatic way to do this would be to convert them to Rust primitives using the `as_f64` methods, and then do whatever you need to.

It would be easier if you had a `TypedArray`, which can readily be converted to a vec.

```
let js_array_to_sort = Array::of3(&JsValue::from(1), &JsValue::from(3), &JsValue::from(2));

let rust_vec = js_array_to_sort
    .values().into_iter()
    .map(|js_val|
        js_val.as_f64().unwrap() as i64
    )
    .collect::<Vec<i64>>();

let mut sorted_rust_vec = rust_vec.clone();
sorted_rust_vec.sort();

dbg!(sorted_rust_vec == rust_vec);
```

Comment: Can't do this - Array / JsValue do not implement iter

Comment: @trentcl Also fixed